# Snipping tool's pen color is always white

Tags: windows-10, contrast

I'm using Windows 10 Professional in **high contrast** mode. The problem is when using **snipping tool** to captures screenshots, it's pens do not have many color. **Pens are only white**, and the **highlight tool only black**.

Are there solutions that can change the pens color? May be some tricks in registry can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 **1809** has come with **Snip & Sketch** (Win + Shift + S), which replace Snipping Tool. The pens will have colored **even in High Contrast** mode.